# Package ANE with APK

Tags: android, air, apk, adt

The Adobe documentation is lacking this very important bit, and the "documentation" of the ADT itself is written by a person having a very bad case of OCD, so it's not possible to understand it. I need an advise from someone who actually did it successfully.

Below is a bit from my Ant script that is supposed to package the APK, where I need the ANE files included:

```
  <target name="package-android-quiet"
          description="Packages Android .apk">
    <echo>${source-dir}</echo>
    <exec executable="${adt}" failonerror="true">
      <arg line="-package"/>
      <arg line="-target apk-debug"/>
      <arg line="-storetype PKCS12"/>
      <arg line="-keystore ${certificate}"/>
      <arg line="-storepass ${password}"/>
      <!-- what goes into ${ane}? -->
      <arg line="${ane}"/>
      <arg line="${output}"/>
      <arg line="${application-xml}"/>
      <arg line="${input}"/>
      <arg line="-C ${source-dir}" />
    </exec>
  </target>
```

Suppose I have files Foo.ane and Bar.ane in the `${source-dir}` how do I tell the packager to use them? So far I'm getting an error:

> An implementation for native extension 'Foo' required by the
>   application was not found for the target platform.

If you can do this by any other means, given they are automatic / crossplatform - suggest away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes it's only posting the question helps... a grep on the commandline help finally revealed a `-extdir` option, which appeared to be what I was looking for.

Comment: Please mark your own answer as 'accepted' so people will know this question is not open anymore.